# Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'inject' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, webpack-4

I am having some unwanted error after I build mine react project. It's working fine but some time due to network connectivity site keep loading my chunks and gives me that error but when I reload again it starts working.

[image]

Comment: The `Unexpected token '<'` error often means that the `chunk.js` file was not loaded successfully. Look in the response tab for the `xxxx.chunk.js` request in the Network tab. It should tell you more why it was not loaded. Most likely 404 error.

Comment: It is not 404 error actually it is taking long time to load though its just 20kb in size